# How do I iterate through an array and store it in $message for PHP mail()?

Tags: php

Previously I had issues with arrays and was graciously helped. My problem now is that I have the data in my array, but I need that to be stored into $message so that it will be included when mail() is called. I have chopped up my code and put the relevant piece below.

```
$to =       '"John Smith" <jsmith@theInter.net>';
$subject =  'Report';
$message =  '===========================================' . '<br>' .
//This is where I would want my array to be located; one element     printed on each line.
'===========================================' . '<br>' . '<br>' .
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

My array ($fileList) contains one string per element. I want to have one element per line to be included in the above $message variable.

Thank you for any assistance you can give me.

Comment: What does the data in the array look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use implode

```
implode("<br>", $fileList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = implode( "\n", $fileList );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 
    '===========================================<br>' .
    implode("<br>", $fileList) .
    '===========================================<br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

[implode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) is what you search